# Delay in sorting : Meteor Js

Tags: meteor

I have chat app, and I load last 5 messages in it , do it like this

```
{{#if haseMoreMessages}}
    <div class="loadmore text-center" id="incLimit">Load More</div>
{{/if}}
{{#each messages}}
    {{> message}}
{{/each}}

messages: function(){
   var messages = Messages.find({},{sort:{createdAt:1}}); // I can remove {sort:{createdAt:1}} and all ok, nut it's not fit
   return messages;
},
haseMoreMessages:function(){
   if (Session.get('messageLimit') > Messages.find().count()) return false;
   return true;
}

Messages.find({room: Rooms.findOne({users : { $in : [this.userId]}})._id},{ sort: { createdAt: -1 } , limit : limitM});
```

So when I write new message, for 100ms or more it shows on the top , and after 200ms or more it shows on the bottom, example:

-`mes1`

-`mes2`

-`mes3`

I write `mes4`

-`mes4`

-`mes1`

-`mes2`

-`mes3`

And after some `ms`

-`mes1`

-`mes2`

-`mes3`

-`mes4`

When I remove `{sort:{createdAt:1}}` from `var messages = Messages.find({},{sort:{createdAt:1}})` all shows ok, whithout delay, **BUT** when I click show more button all old messages show on bottom, but they must shows on **TOP** of the page. Thats why I need `{sort:{createdAt:1}}`

So any idea what can I do ?

Comment: where and when do you set `createdAt`? On the client or on the server?

Comment: your code is very confusing because you don't show how it is separated into files and onto client and server. It might help us help you if you fixed that.

Comment: createAt on server, what part of code u need ? I will show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments, the insert happens on the client, but the `createdAt` field is only populated on the server. Meteor hence uses the local database without the `createdAt` field at first to show the result of the insert right away. Then, after a round-trip to the server and update to the query, the sorting happens as expected.

Two options: Do the insert completely on the server, or attach the `createdAt` field already on the client.